# Meteor application not deploying, Errors prevented startup

Tags: npm, meteor, deployment, rocket.chat

I cloned the rocket chat repo on GitHub and ran `meteor npm install && meteor`, it wasn't able to deploy the app and got stuck, so I exited and tried `meteor` but it throws the same error:

```
Errors prevented startup:

While loading plugin `Livechat` from package `rocketchat:livechat`:
child_process.js:635:11: Command failed: C:\web dev\RocketChat\Rocket.Chat\packages\rocketchat-livechat\plugin/build.bat
'C:\web' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

  at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:635:11)
  at execSync (child_process.js:671:15)
  at module (packages/Livechat/plugin/build-livechat.js:20:2)
  at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
  at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
  at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
  at <runJavaScript-36>:94:1
  at <runJavaScript-36>:99:3


Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
Started MongoDB.
```

And gets stuck there.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is with the space in the name of your `web deb` folder. This should probably be compensated for in the package code, but since it isn't the easiest solution would be to rename your folder to not have a space in the name and then maybe file a issue in the appropriate repo.

Comment: It's not throwing an error anymore, but it's just stuck saying `Linking` so I haven't been able to confim if it's working or not yet. I will update whether it works or not. Thank you